# Should my /usr/local/bin be 700 permissions?

Tags: permissions, osx, directory-structure

I just installed [npm and node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/download/), and I couldn't access `npm`.  And I'm like "why?" and my OS is like "because /usr/local/bin is at 700 permissions" and I'm like "should it really be that way?"  /usr/local is supposed to be .. the local user's bin folder?  Then why does it require root access?

It is filled with GAE stuff.  Maybe Google App Engine changed it, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `/usr/local/bin` and pretty much everything in it should be set 755.

Comment: Or perhaps `775` if you want to have a non-root group with permission to update it.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issues often happen when partitions with non linux FS-Types (vFAT, NTFS..) are used for linux standard directories.
Please check first your FS type :

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep `df /usr/local/bin | grep dev | awk '{print $1}'`
```

The last element is your file-system type.